# Frameworks to reuse HTML compatible with bootstrap and knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I've been working on a project where we are using bootstrap and kockout.js to handle the views but I'm noticing we're copy'ing a lot of the HTML.

We've tried some options like google closure and JQuery.load but we've had errors with both.
Closure couldn't compile because of bootstrap and Jquery load gave us CORS problems.

As an example, we would like to use "templates" for the navigation bar and for the user control panel that is on every page.

Do you guys know some frameworks that are compatible with our setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use plain knockout there is a template binding:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Or you can look for DurandalJS. This is a framework which uses Knockout as templating engine.
http://durandaljs.com/

If you use Visual Studio you can checkout the Hottowel SPA template of John Papa. This gives a initial setup for working with DurandalJS.
http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel-1-1-with-durandal-2-now-available/

Another option you can do is looking in the source code for the template binding to see how the template is injected in the element. You could create a new binding based on the template binding with your own loading meganism.

After a quick bing I also find a nice blogpost about lazy loading templates, which is worth a look:
http://blog.vosnax.ru/2013/06/03/Knockoutjs-lazy-template/

Answer (score 0):

You should try Angular in my opinion. It offers a simpler template structure than knockout and allows very easy JSON calls to web API's

http://angularjs.org/